# JSF Ajax - How to access facesContext.validationFailed in javascript code?

Tags: jsf

I'm building a form to let user send message to me via pure JSF (not Primefaces), here is the form:

```
<h:form id="messageForm" prependId="false">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
                    <p class="errorMessage" style="text-align: center;">Encountered validation error(s), please correct the fields below and submit it again.</p>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <label for="name">Your name * </label><h:message for="name" styleClass="errorMessage" /><br />
                <h:inputText id="name" name="name" size="100" required="true" value="#{messageForm.name}"
                             requiredMessage="Your name is required" /><br /><br />

                <label for="email">Your email * </label><h:message for="email" styleClass="errorMessage" /><br />
                <h:inputText id="email" name="email" size="100" required="true" value="#{messageForm.email}"
                             requiredMessage="Your email is required"
                             validator="#{emailValidator.validate}" /><br /><br />

                <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
                <h:inputText id="subject" name="subject" size="100" value="#{messageForm.subject}" /><br /><br />

                <label for="message">Your message</label><br />
                <h:inputTextarea id="message" cols="90" rows="15" value="#{messageForm.message}" /><br />

                <h:commandButton styleClass="submitButton" action="#{messageForm.send}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" onevent="handleComplete" />
                </h:commandButton>
                &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;<span style="color: #ffff00; font-style: italic;">Note: fields marked with * symbol are required!</span>
            </h:form>
```

Is there any way to make **`facesContext.validationFailed`** accessible to JS function **`handleComplete`** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with a little trick. You can put the value inside a hidden input (or a hidden span/div/...) and then retrieve the value.

1) In your form put the following (ex: right before `</h:form>`):

```
<input type="hidden" id="validation-failed" value="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
```

2) Make sure it is rendered when you submit (you're fine as you render `@form`). If it's outside the form, you can wrap it inside a `h:panelGroup` and render the panelGroup.

3) In handleComplete, do something like:

```
function handleComplete(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') { // Values are updated
        var validationFailed = document.getElementById('validation-failed').value === 'true';

        // ...
    }
}
```

It will look like this:

```
<h:form id="messageForm" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
        <p class="errorMessage" style="text-align: center;">Encountered validation error(s), please correct the fields below and submit it again.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <label for="name">Your name * </label><h:message for="name" styleClass="errorMessage" /><br />
    <h:inputText id="name" name="name" size="100" required="true" value="#{messageForm.name}"
                 requiredMessage="Your name is required" /><br /><br />

    <label for="email">Your email * </label><h:message for="email" styleClass="errorMessage" /><br />
    <h:inputText id="email" name="email" size="100" required="true" value="#{messageForm.email}"
                 requiredMessage="Your email is required"
                 validator="#{emailValidator.validate}" /><br /><br />

    <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
    <h:inputText id="subject" name="subject" size="100" value="#{messageForm.subject}" /><br /><br />

    <label for="message">Your message</label><br />
    <h:inputTextarea id="message" cols="90" rows="15" value="#{messageForm.message}" /><br />

    <h:commandButton styleClass="submitButton" action="#{messageForm.send}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" onevent="handleComplete" />
    </h:commandButton>
    &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;<span style="color: #ffff00; font-style: italic;">Note: fields marked with * symbol are required!</span>

    <input type="hidden" id="validation-failed" value="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleComplete(data) {
        if (data.status === 'success') { // Values are updated
            var validationFailed = document.getElementById('validation-failed').value === 'true';

            // ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: handleComplete() is parameterless JS function...anyway where does data parameter come from ?

Comment: It is automatically passed by the `onevent` of `f:ajax`.

Comment: so how many parameters automatically passed by f:ajax, thanks?

Comment: Only one (`data`), as far as I know.